# Sending uploaded file stuck the window of a browse

Tags: files, settings, browser, file-sharing, upload

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 in my PC.
Everything was good but few days ago I can't no more send files after uploading it, it made stuck all tabs of the window and I also realized that the settings option is no longer there, i tried Wifi settings but it's not opening the settings